# NoClassDefFoundError for GooglePlayServicesUtil Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Messaging .when i am runing the application it is throwing exception that is

```
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at com.corporate.test.HomePage.checkPlayServices(HomePage.java:211)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at com.corporate.test.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:140)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-21 18:46:14.991: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my Activity Code is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.nextra.utils.AppState;

public class HomePage extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout mytrips_relative, approval_relative,
            view_transations_relative;
    Button backViewTransations, continueViewTransactions;
    ImageView logout;
    final Context context = this;
    public String TAG = "HomePage";
    boolean isConnected;
    /*
     * GCM Client Variables
     * */
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    String SENDER_ID = "XXXX";
    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    Context contextGCM;

    String regid;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")

    /*
     * GCM Client Variables END
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);



        /*
         * GCM PlayServices On
         * */
        contextGCM = getApplicationContext();

        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        // GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(contextGCM);
            Log.d("Registration id ", regid + "");
            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }





    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check device for Play Services APK.
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If it
     * doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from the
     * Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            application's context.
     * @param regId
     *            registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service, if there
     * is one.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     * 
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION,
                Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(contextGCM);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    Log.d("registration Id", regid + "");
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over
                    // HTTP, so it
                    // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the
                    // device will send
                    // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message
                    // using the
                    // 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(contextGCM, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }




}
```

See i have installed `Google Play Services` and also done the Build Path Still i am getting the error.

Comment: How did you configure your build path?

Comment: did u import the library in your workspace and added reference to it.

Comment: i done all that is required but it is not working

Comment: did you see a ClassNotFoundException or ExceptionInInitializerError?  you can see possible reasons here - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error under Android Studio 0.3.1.  In the build.gradle file, I added "play-services" (v3.2.0 or higher) to get:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
}
```

I had to restart Android Studio before this finally worked.  Use the Tools>Android>SDKManager to make sure the Google Play "extras" are installed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried every advice I could find, re-creating the library project at least twice.

Then Eclipse ran out of memory, funny because I have 64 GB of RAM.

I decided to restart Windows. When everything was back up, it just worked. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported Google Play Services project and added is as a dependent library to your project. Go to the imported project properties -> Android section and check the box "Is Library"

Then add it as you project dependency. If you're using Eclipse, go to your project Properties -> Android section and in he library section, add the imported Google Play Services project.

Also, fixing your project properties and cleaning can also help you. Try right-clicking in your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project properties. Then, clear your project and try running your project.

Answer (score -2):

This error occures when class on which depends your code wasn't found in runtime. Usually that means someting is wrong with packaging and/or deploy of your code. Check settings of your IDE, try to rebuild the whole project.

Comment: What you say is pretty obvious from the error message.  In order to be helpful, you need to give suggestions as to which library is missing and how to add it.